# MySQL: Count ids that only have only a specific action and how many days that action was taken

Tags: mysql, sql

With a database of actions (starting at 1 and going up), I need to drop all rows of any parentid with a single action = 2, then take the remaining and count the number of actions happened on different days.

Here is my sample data:

| id | datecre | action | parentid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00 | 1 | 52 |
| 2 | 2022-01-02 01:00:00 | 1 | 52 |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 02:00:00 | 1 | 52 |
| 4 | 2022-01-03 01:00:00 | 1 | 65 |
| 5 | 2022-01-04 01:00:00 | 1 | 65 |
| 6 | 2022-01-05 01:00:00 | 1 | 65 |
| 7 | 2022-01-06 01:00:00 | 1 | 65 |
| 8 | 2022-01-07 01:00:00 | 1 | 72 |
| 9 | 2022-01-07 02:00:00 | 2 | 72 |

I have tried several queries:

```
WITH overpass(parentid, date) AS
(
    SELECT parentid, DATE(datecre) as date
    FROM good
    WHERE parentid NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT parentid
        FROM good
        WHERE action=2)
        GROUP BY date
)
SELECT parentid, COUNT(date) as days
FROM overpass
GROUP BY date;
```

Notice parentid 72 is not in the list, because it has a row with action = 2.

This outputs:

| parentid | days |
| --- | --- |
| 52 | 1 |
| 52 | 1 |
| 65 | 1 |
| 65 | 1 |
| 65 | 1 |
| 65 | 1 |

A [DB Fiddle of this query is here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9Nqy7Ni).

The desired output is:

| parentid | days |
| --- | --- |
| 52 | 2 |
| 65 | 4 |

I also tried these final queries with the CTE:

```
select parentid, sum(parentid) from overpass group by date;
select parentid, sum(date) from overpass group by date;
select parentid, count(date) from overpass;
select parentid, sum(parentid) from overpass;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have overcmplicated this problem as a combination of group by on parent id, counting distinct values of dates, while excluding action=2 will do fine without any CTEs:

```
select parentid, count(distinct date(datecre)) cnt
from good g2
where not exists (select 1 from good g where g.action=2 and g.parentid=g2.parentid)
group by parentid
```

Comment: I noticed this didn't actually work in production. I just learned about DB fiddle, so I updated the question to include a fiddle. Here is a fiddle with your answer. https://dbfiddle.uk/tMsspdOo

Comment: thanks for the answer, I don't know what to do to fix it to work tho.

Comment: @JamesRisner there was a typo in the code (now fixed): https://dbfiddle.uk/svZ5_vJA

Comment: I just clarified why 72 shouldn't be listed. @forpas any other clarifications I should make in the question?

Comment: @JamesRisner it seems ok.